# Why are there visual studio version specific lib/dll files provided by some vendors?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

Check, https://www.rti.com/free-trial/dds-files. If you take a look at the download section under Windows, you would see different installers for different versions of visual studio. After inspection, I can say one of the major differences between this installers is that the DLLs resided in the installers are different. These DLLs are used to import some shared functions for my c++ development. After some research I found that not only RTI does this, but there are some libraries by other vendors which are visual studio specific as well. Theoretically, what could be the reason for the vendor deciding to seperate the DLLs according to visual studio versions? What happens if I don't use visual studio to compile the c++ files? Would the DLL still work (assuming the DLL is built with the correct arch type and is built using c++)? I just don't see why an IDE (visual studio) has impact on DLLs.

Comment: Because the build tools differ from VS to VS version. In between build tools the implementation of, say, the STD classes may have breaking changes in between. Same applies to when one compiles under different GCC versions for example

Comment: You could use a newer visual studio version and build with older visual studio build tools though.

Comment: @Neijwiert Doesn't GCC have a higher commitment to keeping *binary* compatibility for their standard library?

Comment: @Deduplicator Could be, but I'm pretty sure there isn't a guarantee that it will be.

Comment: @Neijwiert https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html#abi.versioning.goals

Comment: @Deduplicator I stand corrected, you're right. It is still mentioned under goals, so I'm not sure that it is a 100% guarantee for all edge-cases. IMHO it wouldn't be a bad idea to compile with the earliest GCC version of all the libs you're using.

Comment: An IDE doesn't have an impact on DLLs.   The compiler and library, which that IDE uses, does -  for example, updates of the standard library, change of calling conventions or ABIs, that change between versions of the compiler and library.    Practically, it is reasonable to expect Microsoft will ship each update of their IDE with the latest/contemporary version of their compiler and library.

Comment: These downloads are enormous, at half a gig I'd imagine they included a whole bunch of sample projects.  Too large to wait for.  Do check the manual, a DLL can be reasonably isolated from the compiler version but a static library can not.